# How can i set invalid to "mat-form-field"?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Input data : angular 6, angular material 2.

My custom validation "password-matcher" set invalid for "passGroup".
Example:

```html
         <div ngModelGroup="passGroup" password-matcher #passGroup="ngModelGroup">
             <div class="formGroup">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input
                        matInput
                        type="password"
                        class='inputs'
                        [(ngModel)]='reg.password'
                        name='password'
                        required
                        minlength="8"
                        (input)='onChangeReg(reg)'
                        >
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div class="formGroup">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input
                        matInput
                        type="password"
                        class='inputs'
                        [(ngModel)]='reg.repeatPassword'
                        name='repeatPassword'
                        required
                        minlength="8"
                        (input)='onChangeReg(reg)'
                        >
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I set invalid to `mat-form-field` , if `ngModelGrou`p is `invalid`?
for example:  `<mat-form-field setValidation='passGroup.invalid'>`

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you would need to provide a custom `ErrorStateMatcher` for the `MatInput` control. Angular Material has an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/deyrvmrxmkm?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html). In the `ErrorStateMatcher`'s `isErrorState` function you will need to access the control's parent group and use it's state to return the state for the field control.

However, I'm not sure this will work as expected. Because the parent group state is dependent on the child control state, you are creating a circular dependency. So instead, you might need to check the other child controls for errors rather than explicitly checking the parent state.

From a design perspective, in general you probably shouldn't do this, because the point of showing errors is to bring the user's attention to which fields need correction. Marking a field that has no error as in error when it is another field that has the error will confuse users. In the case of a login control with only username and password fields, I can see that this might be beneficial in order to discourage hacking.

Comment: I see no circular dependency here, he will have to use passed model anywy and ignore matcher call arguments.

Comment: How do you not see that form group's state depending on control's states depending on form group's state is not a circular dependency?